# Trouble getting ElectronPlayer to work on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, netflix, electron

I been trying to get ElectronPlayer(for Netflix) to work on Lubuntu, it does seem to install successfully but I cannot find where it installed to open it, and when trying to open it via the terminal, it doesn't open.

I was able to get ElectronPlayer to work on Ubuntu with no problems, but I really prefer to use Lubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I am using Lubuntu version 19.04 and tried the Discover Software Center to install ElectronPlayer.

I also do not have much experience with Linux.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Telling us your release of Lubuntu maybe useful; Lubuntu 18.04 LTS uses LXDE, where as Lubuntu 18.10 upwards use LXQt.  How did you install ElectronPlayer also?  Snap (https://snapcraft.io/electronplayer) or other?

Comment: if you install chrome downloaded from google netfilx will just work

Comment: you could try a couple things to find it... try something like `ls /usr/bin |grep -i electron` or if you install locate then you can easily search your drive for the application... if you want to get really old school you could use "find" (`man find`) but I find it very slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to what ships with 19.04, you need to upgrade to **`snapd` 2.39.2+19.04** for Electron Player to show up in the **"Other"** category of the menu. Additionally, this upgrade will need to be in place in order for a functional version of Electron Player (**2.0.7 rev 9**) to be installed correctly.

Oddly, *upgrading `snapd` in Discover does not seem to provide the fix*, so to upgrade `snapd`:

1. Open System Tools → Qterminal
2. Enter `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install snapd` and press Enter
3. When asked for your password, enter it and press Enter

While you're there you can easily install Electron Player from the terminal:

1. Enter `sudo snap install electronplayer` and press Enter
2. Enter your password if asked and press Enter
3. When completed, run it by entering `electronplayer` and pressing Enter

Since you already have Electron Player installed, you could upgrade `snapd` as above, but you would still face problems if you try to run Electron Player:

```
(electronplayer:2917): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:15:17.454: cannot open display: :0
```

To ensure that everything is working correctly, remove then install Electron Player: `sudo snap remove electronplayer && sudo snap install electronplayer`.